# How to prune a Salix Integra recovering from scale infestation

Tags: trees, plant-health, pruning

I just wondered if you could point me in the right direction with regard to pruning my Salix Integra. Im just about to treat it for a scale infestation and could do with some tips.

Here's a picture

[image: Salix Integra]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job Matt...quick! You understand that both your Willow on a stem and your little maple will never get taller?  I'll draw something to explain some of the pruning.  You'll need pruning hedge shears.  How many hedges and shrubs do you have in your yard?  I'd get Felco or Sandvik Pradines P51. Learn how to sharpen and they will last forever.  Think of a large salad bowl turned upside down. Put your shears so they are tangent to the circumference of the 'bowl.'  The sides of the bowl gradually slope so that leaves on the lowest part of the bowl are getting (relatively) as much light as the leaves on the top of this plant.  Always clean shears with rubbing alcohol before and after cutting each different individual plant. I'll send more pruning information or draw something for you.  It is important to prune out branches and leaves that aren't producing much food for the plant.  The plant will on its own cut these branches/leaves off from nutrients/water if they aren't good producers.  You are simply speeding up the process and controlling where the energy is being spent and keeping your plant healthy from energy drains.  Never leave stumps of branches.  No covering any cuts.  Allow to air dry. Your little maple will get wider but no taller.  Part of the beauty with these Japanese maples is branch structure.  You don't want a 'Cousin It'...remember the Munsters?  This shall date you!!  Grin. I'll be back, make sure you get a few great tools...a Felco hand pruner, bypass (never anvil), and Sandvik hedge shears.  A great sharpening stone or file.  Rubbing alcohol.  There was once a time I got lazy, didn't clean my pruners and passed a major viral disease.  Now I am super sensitive. Take care of the scale first, you've got time.

Comment: It's not a Japanese maple, might want to correct that

Comment: The little shrub to the left of the Salix?  I'll try blowing it up, forget I can do that...

Comment: Perhaps a closer look?  What I wanted to get across about pruning was you will want to 'head' your willow  and 'thin' your...Japanese maple. What is it??

Comment: the question is about the willow.  It helps everyone reading the question if you keep the focus on what the original question asked about.

Comment: Just wanted to add that pruning that particular salix is very different from say that 'Japanese Maple' or whatever it is.

Comment: What do you think it is Kevinsky?  Even though it is off-topic.  Some of the best ideas come from the periphery!!  Gardening is so very complex and some of us should be given a bit more leash if we see something the client doesn't see that maybe should.  Just sayin'...GRIN!!

Comment: I'd like to see the base of this Salix int. Hakuru Nishiki...something like that.  Soil, mulch and even too thick ground covers will keep the bark too moist and allow for bacteria to girdle this pretty plant.  Killing it in a year or two.  There is a definite line where roots begin and belong under good soil.  Above that line is bark that should always be free of soil, mulch, rocks, ground cover so that air keeps it dry and free of bacteria and decomposers.  All woody perennials demand this...this is one of the top 3 reasons people lose their plants...

Answer (score 2):

Clip over with shears to reshape in July - heavier pruning should be done in early spring, just before growth begins, or late autumn, but don't prune back past the graft point at the stop of the standard stem. You don't need to prune it back to deal with the scale, just to reshape at this time of year.